# How to integral $z^{\prime\prime}+ 2 \eta z^\prime=0$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

From the given ODE, $$z^{\prime\prime} + 2 \eta z^\prime = 0 $$
The rest procedure is as below
$$\int \frac{z^{\prime\prime}}{z^\prime} d \eta = \int -2 \eta \, d \eta$$
$$ \ln z^\prime = - \eta ^2 + c_0 $$
$$ z^\prime = \frac{d z}{d \eta} = C_1 \exp (- \eta ^2 )$$
$$ z(\eta) = c_1 \int _0 ^{\eta} {\exp (-x^2) } \, {d x  } + c_2$$

I'd like to know how the fraction of derivatives ($z^{\prime\prime}/z^\prime$) is integrated as $\ln z^\prime$.

There are similar equations but there is not exactly the same one.

Comment: I think you mean $C_1\int_0^\eta\exp(-x^2)dx+C_2$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. =) Thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take into account that $z'=\frac{dz}{d\eta}$ and $\frac{d\log z'}{d\eta}=\frac{1}{z'}\frac{dz'}{d\eta}=\frac{z''}{z'}$. The rest is just an application of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int \dfrac {z''}{z'}d\eta$$
Since $z''=\dfrac {dz'}{d \eta}$:
$$I=\int \dfrac {dz'}{d \eta}  \dfrac {d\eta}{z'}$$
Therefore:
$$I=\int \dfrac {dz'}{z'} =C+\ln |z'| $$

---

You can also substitute $u=z'$ then the DE is a first linear DE:
$$z'' + 2 \eta z'=0$$
$$u' + 2 \eta u=0$$
This is separable. It leads to the same result.
$$\int \dfrac {du}u =- 2 \int \eta d\eta$$

Comment: I also appreciate your explanation, too. It's quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's a funny thing.  You have to treat the second derivative of $z$ as a fraction.

$\int \frac{z''}{z'} d\eta =\int \frac{1}{z'} \cdot \frac{dz'}{d\eta } d\eta $

As you can see, the differential terms $d\eta$ cancel each other out.

Use the identity

$ \begin{array}{l}
 \int \frac{1}{x} dx=ln( x) +C\\
\\
\int \frac{z''}{z'} d\eta =\int \frac{1}{z'} \cdot \frac{dz'}{d\eta } d\eta =\int \frac{1}{z'} dz'=ln( z') +C
\end{array}$

Originally, the derivative was meant to be a fraction.  It still works as a fraction, but its meaning has evolved to be more of a notation.  It's a similar story for the integral notation.

Comment: I could understand it easily thanks to your answer.